# Overwrite .bash_profile file in linux

Tags: linux

in my **.bash_profile** file 
i want to update value of PATH variable.
Also, want to add **JAVA_PATH** and **JRE_HOME** variables.
And, I want to do all this with **Shell Script**.

I have no idea about how to do this with commands, so I **overwrite** the entire file using **cat** command-

```
cat >> ~/.bash_profile << _EOF_
#!/bin/bash/
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
.~/.bashrc
fi

#User specific environment and startup programs
JAVA_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_35/bin
PATH=$JAVA_PATH:$PATH:HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/jdk1.6.0_35

export PATH
unset USERNAME
_EOF_
```

What would be the impact of doing so with this file?
How i can easily update value of **PATH** variable and insert **JAVA_PATH** and **JRE_HOME** variables in this file?

Comment: Since you use `>>` for redirection instead of `>`, you are actually _appending_, not overwriting.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Java changing location all the time after updates? Why not use symlinks in the filesystem to point to the current version? Then your .bash_profile can stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some text manipulation tool - like sed or awk...

Here is simple example of how to change the PATH value in your .bash_profile

```
sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*PATH=\)\(.*\)$/\1"\/bin:\/usr\/bin:~\/bin"/' ~/.bash_profile
```

Notice the escaped special characters ( and /

It you want to overwrite your old file, you need to do it through temporary file like:

```
sed ... > /tmp/tmpbashprofile$$
mv /tmp/tmpbashprofile$$ ~/.bash_profile
```

Adding new settings is easy:

```
echo "JAVA_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_35/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Notice the double >> - it appends data to specified file

Comment: echo "JAVA_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_35/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile
will append to the last line.
But how we can append it before export PATH unset USERNAME

Comment: Use command like sed 's/^\(export PATH\)$/JAVA_PATH=\/usr\/java\/jdk1.6.0_35\/bin\n\1/' ~/.bash_profile ... use it the same way as in my answer...